# PHP nested if/else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to know may I put "if else" inside of different "if else" in PHP?
    Thank you.

```
For example:
if(...){
......
}
elseif(...){
      elseif(...){
            .....
           }
}
```

Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes of course you can, but not a unattached `elseif`. An elseif must have a starting IF

Comment: You can't have an "else" without an "if".  It wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Maybe you should look up what an `ifelse` actually is

Comment: `may I put "if else" inside of different "if else" `->yes. but `else if` or `else` without `if`? no way man

Comment: maybe you can try http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much.
Grateful to everyone․

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about syntax no you can't.
Cause once you are inside of the elseif block php expects you to start with if.
If it's about coding always try to avoid if elseif. Most of the cases switch case does the trick. In other case [return early pattern](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/wiki/Return-Early-Pattern) does the trick(this is my favorite and cleanest solution IMO).

Comment: To whoever down-voted my answer I would love to hear their reason :)